# Find highest total from 2d array and print in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, 2d, max

So here I am trying to take some ints from the array and add them per row. 
I then store the sum as rowTotal. If rowTotal is greater than maxRow.... 
I'm tired. Can someone please point out the obvious?

```
     int maxRow = 0;
     int playNum = 0;

     for(int col = 0;col < score[0].length;col++)
        maxRow += score[0][col];
     for(int row = 1;row < score.length;row++)
     {
         int rowTotal = 0;
         for(int col = 0;col < score[row].length;col++)    
             rowTotal += score[row][col];
         if(rowTotal>maxRow)  
         {
             playNum = row;
             maxRow = rowTotal;
         }
         System.out.println("Player " + (playNum + 1) + " is victorious with a score of " + maxRow);
     }
```

Comment: @Ferret9, thank you for making the code readable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the `System.out.println` out of the second for loop. Also, you can do away with the first for loop.

```
 int maxRow = 0;
 int playNum = 0;
 for(int row = 0;row < score.length;row++)
 {
     int rowTotal = 0;
     for(int col = 0;col < score[row].length;col++) 
     {
         rowTotal += score[row][col];
     }
     if(rowTotal>maxRow)  
     {
         playNum = row;
         maxRow = rowTotal;
     }

 }
 System.out.println("Player " + (playNum + 1) + " is victorious with a score of " + maxRow);
```

Comment: I am trying to find the row with the greatest total and print the row number as to declare a winner.  The problem is that it prints out more than one winner. Its works fine with only two players, but more than that it prints as many as five winners.

Comment: The reason for that is the System.out.println() in the for loop. Take it out of that and it will work fine. I have done that in my code snippet.

Comment: I think the flaw is in my logic, not a code error.  This is my first ever program in any language so I still miss obvious stuff all the time.

Comment: Ah, I thought I was taking the row number with the first for loop and using that as my player number.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Good Job!. t was the Sys.prin in the loop. Moved it and it works great. You guys are the best. Time for sleep. Thank You.

Comment: To explain the problem further, your code is working fine for two players because the second loop only runs once for two players. So, if there are n players, your code will print n-1 winners. You need to print the message after all rows have been processed. Can you accept the best answer please?

Answer (score 0):

1. You're starting row from 1, should be 0
2. Why do you change maxRow += score[0][col]; ?

These should fix your problem, though I don't know what it is

Answer (score 0):

Well the `System.out.println(..` should be outside of the loop.

Otherwise I don't see a problem with this, other than the fact that the code could be improved upon (shortened). What errors/unexpected results are you getting?

Comment: I am trying to find the row with the greatest total and print the row number as to declare a winner. The problem is that it prints out more than one winner. Its works fine with only two players, but more than that it prints as many as five winners. –

Comment: Do exactly what @Priyesh and I have suggested. That will fix the problem. Replace your code with what Priyesh wrote.

Answer (score 0):

If you start the second `for` loop from index zero then there is no need for the first `for` loop as far as I can tell.  Not sure why you were summing `maxRow` in the first loop anyway, unless I'm completely missing the point.